# Nested array group-by with lodash

Tags: javascript

I have a small web-application which fetches data using API call, the response is array of reports, each report have unique id, application, type and title.

I want to map it into new object by grouping-by application and then by types
as describe bellow.

#### Input:

```
[
  {
    "id": "REPORT1",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT2",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT3",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE2",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT4",
    "application": "APP2",
    "type": "TYPE3",
    "title": ""
  }
]
```

#### Desired output:

```
{
  "APP1": {
    "TYPE1": [
      {
        "id": "REPORT1",
        "application": "APP1",
        "type": "TYPE1",
        "title": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "REPORT2",
        "application": "APP1",
        "type": "TYPE1",
        "title": ""
      }
    ],
    "TYPE2": [
      {
        "id": "REPORT3",
        "application": "APP1",
        "type": "TYPE2",
        "title": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "APP2": {
    "TYPE3": [
      {
        "id": "REPORT4",
        "application": "APP2",
        "type": "TYPE3",
        "title": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With `loadash` I came up with this:

```
const output = _(input)
  .groupBy(report => report.application)
  .value()
```

After group by `application`, I need to make another nested grouping or mapping by `type` but got stuck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be implemented quite easily without lodash via [the `Array#reduce()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

For details on how this is achieved, see the comments in code snippets source code:

```js
var input = [{
    "id": "REPORT1",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT2",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT3",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE2",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT4",
    "application": "APP2",
    "type": "TYPE3",
    "title": ""
  }
];

var output = input.reduce((result, item) => {

  // Get app object corresponding to current item from result (or insert if not present)
  var app = result[item.application] = result[item.application] || {};

  // Get type array corresponding to current item from app object (or insert if not present)
  var type = app[item.type] = app[item.type] || [];

  // Add current item to current type array
  type.push(item);

  // Return the result object for this iteration
  return result;

}, {});

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
height:100% !important;
max-height:unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Good job doing it without loadash :)

Comment: Thx for mentioning reduce ……

Comment: You're welcome @HossamMaher

Comment: hey ! Do you know how to type this function with typescript ? and type the output ? Thanks

Comment: @Gautier something like this might work? https://gist.github.com/dacre-denny/a86211ea59e54cd03474db0106578888

Comment: @DacreDenny : indeed, I end up doing this : type ObjectProductsWithPrices = {
  [key: string] : {
    [key: string]: {
      [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: ProductWithPriceAndDate[]
      }
    }
  }
};

Answer (score 7):

es6, object spreading and reduce makes it so simpler

```js
const input = [
  {
    "id": "REPORT1",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT2",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT3",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE2",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT4",
    "application": "APP2",
    "type": "TYPE3",
    "title": ""
  }
]


const output = input.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  ...acc,
  [item.application]: {
    ...acc[item.application],
    [item.type]: [
      ...(acc[item.application] && acc[item.application][item.type] || []),
      item,
    ]
  }
}), {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could take a dynamic approach with the wanted keys for grouping.

> ```
> groups = ["application", "type"]
> ```

Then reduce the data array and the keys array and build either new objects, if necessary or with the last group an array for pushing the actual object.

This solution can be easily extended to more nested groups, if necessary.

```js
var data = [{ id: "REPORT1", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE1", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT2", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE1", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT3", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE2", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT4", application: "APP2", type: "TYPE3", title: "" }],
    groups = ["application", "type"],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups
            .reduce((group, key, i, { length }) =>
                group[o[key]] = group[o[key]] || (i + 1 === length ? [] : {}), r)
            .push(o);

        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I personally found this more readable when combining _.groupBy and _.mapValues in Lodash:

```js
var input = [{ id: "REPORT1", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE1", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT2", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE1", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT3", application: "APP1", type: "TYPE2", title: "" }, { id: "REPORT4", application: "APP2", type: "TYPE3", title: "" }]

const output = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(input, i => i.application),app => _.groupBy(app, i => i.type))

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it still readable when you group by by 5 keys, what about 10 keys?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a short method to do this, check below snippet.

```js
const groupByDeep = (collection, keys) => {
  return _.chain(collection)
    .map(item => _.map(keys, key => _.get(item, key)))
    .reduce((result, paths, idx) => {
      const items = _.get(result, paths.join('.'), []);
      _.set(result, paths.join('.'), [...items, collection[idx]]);
      return result;
    }, {})
    .value();
};

const input = [{
    "id": "REPORT1",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT2",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE1",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT3",
    "application": "APP1",
    "type": "TYPE2",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "REPORT4",
    "application": "APP2",
    "type": "TYPE3",
    "title": ""
  }
];

console.log(groupByDeep(input, ['application', 'type']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).